# Hashtable not decrementing

Tags: java, hashtable

The value of the hashtable is not decrmenting by 1 in second loop over maga_split array.They stays same as during the first loop.

```
Hashtable<String,Integer> notemap=new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
String[] note_split={give,one,grand,today};
String[] maga_split={give,me,one,grand,today,night};
for(int i=0;i<note_split.length;i++)
        {
            if(!notemap.contains(note_split[i]))
            {
                notemap.put(note_split[i],1);
            }
            else
            {
                notemap.put(note_split[i],notemap.get(note_split[i])+1);
            }
        }


        for(int i=0;i<maga_split.length;i++)
        {
            String s=maga_split[i];
            if(!notemap.contains(s))
            {
                notemap.put(s,1);
            }
            else
            {
                notemap.put(s,notemap.get(s)-1);
            }
        }

        for(Map.Entry s:notemap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(s.getKey()+"="+s.getValue());        }
```

Comment: Please include definition of notemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are using `notemap.contains()`. If you read documentation for `contains()`:

> Tests if some key maps into the specified value in this hashtable. This operation is more expensive than the containsKey method. Note that this method is identical in functionality to containsValue, (which is part of the Map interface in the collections framework).

So you are not testing if key is in table, instead you are testing for value.
When using maps it is good idea to **use `Map` interface where possible**: `Map<String, Integer> notemap = new HashMap<>();`. This way you can be sure you are invoking standard interface for map, and you can switch implementation of map if needed, for example from HashMap to TreeMap.
Then you should use `containsKey()` method